# How hide items when print current page?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I create my web project by Vaadin 7.3.6

When I want to print current page I use this:

```
    import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
    import com.vaadin.ui.Button.ClickListener;

    private ClickListener printListener;    
    printListener = new ClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                    JavaScript.getCurrent().execute("print();");
                }
            };
```

As result it's print current page.
The page content from text and two buttons (**Print**, **OK**) on the bottom of page. Nice.

But I want to print only text. Without this 2 buttons. 
I want to hide buttons **ONLY** when printing current page. 
When return to page I want to see again this two buttons.

How I can do this?

P.S. I try this:

```
final Button okButton = new Button(MessageService.getMessage("ok"));
final Button printButton = new Button(MessageService.getMessage("print"));
printButton.setStyleName("small-top-margin");
final JavaScript js = JavaScript.getCurrent();
    final UI ui = UI.getCurrent();
    printButton.addClickListener(event -> {
        logger.debug("click_print");
        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            ui.access(() -> {
                logger.debug("hide_all_buttons");
                printButton.setVisible(false);
                okButton.setVisible(false);
                js.execute("print();");
            });
            try {
                logger.debug("wating_n_seconds");
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            ui.access(() -> {
                logger.debug("show_all_buttons");
                printButton.setVisible(true);
                okButton.setVisible(true);
            });
        });
        thread.start();
    }); // click listener
```

1. First click on **printButton** - nothing happened
2. Second click on **printButton**  - print all buttons. It's not correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the button easily with button.setVisible(false). The true trick is to get the button back. One one is to do this in thread and have sufficient delay before switching the button back visible. Here is an example (Java 8 syntax to make it more compact) This works both with Vaadin 7 & 8.

```
    final Button print = new Button("Print");
    final UI ui = this; // or UI.getCurrent() or getUI() depending where you are
    final JavaScript js = JavaScript.getCurrent();
    print.addClickListener(event -> {
        Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
            ui.access(() ->  {
                print.setVisible(false);
                js.execute("print();");
            });
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ui.access(() -> print.setVisible(true));
        });
        t.start();
    });
    layout.addComponent(print);
```

Alternative approach is to use theming, I.e.

```
Button print = new Button("Print");
print.addStyleName("no-print");
```

And the following into your mytheme.scss file, before `@mixin mytheme`

```
@media print {
   .no-print {
        display:none; 
   }
}
```

Comment: In line "t.start()"  - I get error:  at myproject.ui.wz.SuccessStepWz.lambda$postInitContent$fd438938$1(SuccessStepWz.java:140). java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException

Comment: I updated the example, check that you got the updates

Comment: Compare your code and the one in my answer, they are different, the creation of the new Thread and calling to start needs to be put into listener. Also js.execute needs to be in ui,access()

Comment: I forgot to mention that Push is needed for this to work. Can you upgrade to Vaadin 7.7.16?

Comment: I found solution: 1. add new custom css: styles.add("@media print {.noPrint { display:none; }}"); 2. in code okButton.setStyleName("noPrint"); And now when print the buttons NOT print

Comment: Yes. Here from official doc: https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/advanced/advanced-printing.html  - "You can hide such elements in CSS, as well as otherwise style the page for printing. Style definitions for printing are defined inside a @media print {} block in CSS."

Comment: Note, instead of using styles.add(..) I would recommend to add this to your theme.